# Cleared countdown timer when you restart the page

Tags: typescript, local-storage

I made a countdown timer on the typescript
now we need to make so that the timer is not reset after a reboot, store in localStorage.
like all true logically made, but still throws

code below:

[PasteBin link](http://pastebin.com/9PAubSM1)

**LS** Class

```
export class LS {
    public set (key: string, data: any) {
        let result = (data.constructor == Object) ? JSON.stringify(data) : data;
        localStorage.setItem(key, result);
    }

    public get (key: string) : any {
        let jsonObject = null;
        let data = localStorage.getItem(key);

        try {
            jsonObject = JSON.parse(data);
        }
        catch(e) {
            jsonObject = data;
        }

        return jsonObject;
    }

    public rm(key:string) {
        localStorage.removeItem(key);
    }
}
```

**CountdownService** class

```
export class CountdownService {
    protected timeData: Object = {
        days: 0,
        hours: 0,
        minutes: 0,
        seconds: 0
    };

    public ONE_SECONDS = 1000;

    protected callback:Function;
    protected ls:LS;
    protected nameTimeData:string = 'timingData';

    constructor() {
        this.ls = new LS();
    }

    public start(hours: number, minutes:number, _callback:Function) {
        this.callback = _callback;
        let milliseconds = this.toMilliseconds(hours, minutes);
        let deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date().toString()) + milliseconds);

        this.initializeClock(deadline);
    }

    public getTimeData():Object {
        return this.timeData
    }

    protected toMilliseconds(hours, minutes) {
        let secondsHours = hours * 3600;
        let secondsMinutes = minutes * 60;
        return (secondsHours + secondsMinutes) * this.ONE_SECONDS;
    }

    protected getTimeRemaining(endTime) {

        let currentTime = new Date().toString();
        /*let lsTime;

        // This block does not work correctly
        if (this.ls.get(this.nameTimeData) != null) {
            lsTime = this.ls.get(this.nameTimeData);
            console.log(lsTime);
            this.ls.set(this.nameTimeData, new Date().toString());
        } else {
            this.ls.set(this.nameTimeData, new Date().toString());
            lsTime = this.ls.get(this.nameTimeData);
        }
*/
        let t = Date.parse(endTime) - Date.parse( currentTime );
        let seconds = Math.floor((t / this.ONE_SECONDS) % 60);
        let minutes = Math.floor((t / this.ONE_SECONDS / 60) % 60);
        let hours = Math.floor((t / (this.ONE_SECONDS * 60 * 60)) % 24);
        let days = Math.floor(t / (this.ONE_SECONDS * 60 * 60 * 24));

        return {
            'total': t,
            'days': days,
            'hours': hours,
            'minutes': minutes,
            'seconds': seconds
        };
    }

    protected initializeClock(endTime) {

        let updateClock = () => {
            let t  = this.getTimeRemaining(endTime);

            this.timeData['days'] = t['days'];
            this.timeData['hours'] = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
            this.timeData['minutes'] = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
            this.timeData['seconds'] = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

            if (t.total <= 0) {
                clearInterval(timeInterval);
                this.callback();
            }
        };

        updateClock();
        var timeInterval = setInterval(updateClock, this.ONE_SECONDS);
    }
}
```

**Calling code**

```
let timeData = this.test['time'].split(':'); 
console.log(timeData); // ["1", "1"]
this.cds.start(timeData[0], timeData[1], this.endTestCallback);
```

Comment: You could have included the code here with the question. Also, please include what type of error does the code throw. Also, shouldn't you be storing the end time, not the current time? You can always get the current time.

Comment: there are no errors, just reset the time when you reboot, which should not be, and the code can not be attached, editor complains

Comment: i saved current time

Comment: I edited the question to include the code. Seemed to work fine.

Comment: OK. Hard to tell what's wrong just by reading the provided code. Would be useful to see how the calling code looks, i.e. the code that calls `CountdownService.start()`. What do you mean 'resets the time'? What do you mean by reboot - close browser tab or reboot the OS? Does this run in a browser? Can you use the debugging tools to see if the localStorage item gets set? Also, you don't seem to be using `lsTime`.  Sorry for the questions, but I don't see why would you need to save the current time for a countdown to a specific date. What is the scenario you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I mean by "reboot" and reload the page only.
local storage is changing as it should.
I'm trying to achieve preservation of the current status of the timer, that he would not reset after reloading the page only.

Comment: let timeData = this.test['time'].split(':');
            console.log(timeData);
            this.cds.start(timeData[0], timeData[1], this.endTestCallback);      //       ["1", "1"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the calling code sets the end time relative to the current time.. Each time you refresh the page, it recalculates a new end time and the counter appears to reset.

You need to adjust your logic - I suggest storing the end time instead. This can be done outside your `CountdownService` class.

Adjust the `CountdownService.start()` method to take a `Date` object (which represents an absolute point in time, instead of a relative offset from current time).

```
public start(deadline: Date, _callback:Function) {
    this.callback = _callback;
    this.initializeClock(deadline);
}
```

In the code where you use the `CountdownService`, use your `LS` service to save the end date if it hasn't been set already. Something like this:

```
let storage = new LS();
let deadline = storage.get('deadline');

if (!deadline) { // set end time if not set already
    let timeData = this.test['time'].split(':'); 

    console.log(timeData); // ["1", "1"]
    // `+new Date` is a trick for converting a date to milliseconds
    deadline = new Date(+new Date() + (timeData[0] * 3600 + timeData[1] * 60) * 1000);
}


this.cds.start(deadline, this.endTestCallback);
```